# Python log file didn't properly write logging messages and only the format

Tags: python, logging

I ran a Python script overnight and found out that the log file is just repeated lines of the message format that I specified rather than the actual messages. In the `main` module, I created the logger as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import os


def main():
    msg_format = '[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s: %(lineno)d (%(funcName)s)] %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=msg_format, level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime(format='%Y%m%d-%H%M')
    log_filename = '_'.join(['log', run_type, timestamp]) + '.txt'
    save_pathname = '_'.join([run_type, datetime.now().strftime(format='%Y%m%d')])
    save_path = os.path.join(save_path, save_pathname)

    if not os.path.exists(save_path):
        os.mkdir(path=save_path)

    log_file = os.path.join(save_path, log_filename)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=log_file)
    file_handler.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(fmt=msg_format)
    logger.addHandler(hdlr=file_handler)
    .
    .
    .
```

I have `logger.info(msg='something')` statements throughout my module. When I opened the log file, all I saw was:

```
[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s: %(lineno)d (%(funcName)s)] %(message)s
[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s: %(lineno)d (%(funcName)s)] %(message)s
[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s: %(lineno)d (%(funcName)s)] %(message)s
[%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s: %(lineno)d (%(funcName)s)] %(message)s
.
.
.
```

What part of the logging initialization went wrong? Am I supposed to explicitly set `filemode='w'` in the `logging.basicConfig`? Thanks.

Comment: `(%funcName)s` should be `%(funcName)s`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thank you.

Comment: do you get the same if you do `logger.info('something')` instead of `logger.info(msg='something')`?

Comment: @gelonida Yes, I do. Would that make a difference? I actually added in the `msg=` because PyLint kept complaining for some reason.

Comment: I was just curious if it makes a difference, as I never saw anybody writing log statements like this. If the problem remains if if you don't use `msg=`, then this will not fix it. On the other hand if you tell me the exact pylint message I can help you to write log statements the usual way, which will probably even be a tiny bit more efficient, especially if you disable logging lateron.

Comment: I think the "usual way" for the majority of Python coding is to exclude the keyword of keyword arguments unless it's necessary. I just like to include them for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works.

Try setting `Formatter` object to `file_handler.setFormatter`

```
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s: %(lineno)d (%(funcName)s) %(message)s'))
```